# Linq distinct not working correctly

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

I'm having a strange problem with a linq query. I'm using LINQPad 4 to make some a query that uses regular expression using LinqToSQL as the LinqPad driver.

Here's the query that I'm trying to make :

```
(from match in
from s in SystemErrors
select Regex.Match(s.Description, "...")
select new 
{
  FamilyCode = match.Groups["FamilyCode"].Value,
  ProductPrefix = match.Groups["ProductPrefix"].Value,
  BillingGroup = match.Groups["BillingGroup"].Value,
  Debtor = match.Groups["Debtor"].Value
}).Distinct()
```

As you can see I'm trying to extract data from a text description in a log table using groups. The query works, but the Distinct doesn't want to work, it returns a line for all Match.

I have read that distinct should work with anonymous type, matching each property. Even more strange is that distinct does actually do something, it orders the values alphabetically by the FamilyCode (and then by ProductPrefix, etc.).

Has someone an idea on why this isn't working?
Thanks

Here is what is displayed in the SQL tab of LinqPad :

```
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = 'Big Regexp'
DECLARE @p1 NVarChar(1000) = 'FamilyCode'
DECLARE @p2 NVarChar(1000) = 'ProductPrefix'
DECLARE @p3 NVarChar(1000) = 'BillingGroup'
DECLARE @p4 NVarChar(1000) = 'Debtor'

SELECT DISTINCT [t2].[Description] AS [input], [t2].[value], [t2].[value2], [t2].[value3], [t2].[value4], [t2].[value5]
FROM (
    SELECT [t1].[Description], [t1].[value], @p1 AS [value2], @p2 AS [value3], @p3 AS [value4], @p4 AS [value5]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t0].[Description], @p0 AS [value]
        FROM [SystemError] AS [t0]
        ) AS [t1]
    ) AS [t2]
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Sql tab to see exactly what SQL is being sent to the server?  That might help with debugging.

Comment: Yes, I tried, but the result is not really useful. I've edited my question to show what is in the SQL tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = from eachError in SystemErrors
             let match = Regex.Match(eachError.Description, "...")
             group eachError by new 
             {
              FamilyCode = match.Groups["FamilyCode"].Value,
              ProductPrefix = match.Groups["ProductPrefix"].Value,
              BillingGroup = match.Groups["BillingGroup"].Value,
              Debtor = match.Groups["Debtor"].Value
             }
             into unique
             select unique.key;
```

When you use `Distinct()`, it's distinct by pointer to each object, not value because `select new {}` is object type not value type. Try using group by instead.

Comment: Of course you could also use this overload: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx

Comment: It was a good idea, but it doesn't work with Group By. If I try, I get an exception that says "Method 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match Match(System.String, System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL"... He doesn't know what to do with the regular expression.

Comment: OK, nevermind I found a workarond, I create an inner query and call ToList() on it and then do the Group By. Works perfectly! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, you can use `.Distinct(IEqualityComparer<T>)` overload and provided EqualityComparer for the object that you want to process.

Comment: That overload of `Distinct` is not supported by LINQ to SQL (or LINQ to Entities, for that matter: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550(v=vs.110).aspx).