# linq to entity return duplicate outputs

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to convert my SQL query to linq to entity.

This is my SQL query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    voidSEVT.RESTYPE, voidSEVT.SESID, voidWO.WONUM, voidSEVT.T_START,
    voidSEVT.USER3
FROM
    VOIDWO AS voidWO 
JOIN 
    voidSEVT ON voidWO.SEQNUM = voidSEVT.SEQNUM 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    PROJECTS AS prj ON voidWO.PRJ_ID = prj.PRJ_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    RESTYPE ON voidSEVT.RTYPE = RESTYPE.CODE 
JOIN
    RSRCE as resource on voidSEVT.RESID = resource.RESID
WHERE
    (voidSEVT.USERFLAG4 != 1) 
    AND (LRTRIM(RTRIM(voidSEVT.USER3)) <> '')
```

my sql query output is

```
  RESTYPE   SESID   WONUM            T_START    USER3     
0                   7245100 1477491          1352239200 0030\r\n0060\r\n
4                   7245098 1477491          1352239200 0030\r\n0060\r\n
4                   7245099 1477491          1352239200 0030\r\n0060\r\n
5                   7245097 1477491          1352239200 0030\r\n0060\r\n
5                   7245101 1477491          1352239200 0030\r\n0060\r\n
```

This is my linq to entity

```
public List<ReversalEntity> ReversalList()
{
   var db = new SchedwinEntities();
   var query = 
                ( from voidWO in db.VOIDWOes
                  join voidSEVT in db.VOIDSEVTs on voidWO.SEQNUM equals voidSEVT.SEQNUM into voidSEVT_join
                  from voidSEVT in voidSEVT_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  join prj in db.PROJECTS on voidWO.PRJ_ID equals prj.PRJ_ID into prj_join
                  from prj in prj_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  from voidSevtJoin in voidSEVT_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  join restype in db.RESTYPEs on voidSevtJoin.RTYPE equals restype.CODE into RESTYPEs_join
                  from restypes in RESTYPEs_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  join resource in db.RSRCEs on voidSEVT.RESID equals resource.RESID into RSRCS_join
                  where
                    (voidSEVT.USERFLAG4.value != 1) &&
                    (voidSEVT.USER3.Trim().Length > 0)

   select new
   {
       resourceType = voidSEVT.RESTYPE,
       voidSEVT.SESID,
       wonum = voidWO.WONUM,
       start = voidSEVT.T_START,
       usage = voidSEVT.USER3,
       SAPCCr = ((voidSEVT.RESTYPE == 5 || voidSEVT.RESTYPE == 0)?prj.USER3:prj.USER9),
       activity = restypes.USER2,
       sendercc = restypes.USER1,
       resdesc = RSRCS_join.FirstOrDefault().DES,
       Type=voidSEVT.RESTYPE,
       jobdesc = voidWO.JOBDESC,
   }).Distinct();
```

my sql query return 20 recrords like below

```
    RESTYPE   SESID   WONUM            T_START    USER3     
0                   7245100 1477491          1352239200 0030\r\n0060\r\n
0                   7245100 1477491          1352239200 0030\r\n0060\r\n
0                   7245100 1477491          1352239200 0030\r\n0060\r\n
0                   7245100 1477491          1352239200 0030\r\n0060\r\n
4                   7245098 1477491          1352239200 0030\r\n0060\r\n
4                   7245098 1477491          1352239200 0030\r\n0060\r\n
4                   7245098 1477491          1352239200 0030\r\n0060\r\n
4                   7245098 1477491          1352239200 0030\r\n0060\r\n
etc...
```

basically each record have 3 duplicates for each record so the total count is 20 on my output.look like some how the joins are not appropriate here but not sure .

Some one advise me what am missing here please ?

Comment: hi, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441659/linq-distinct-not-working-correctly try this

Comment: You have 4 outer joins with linq vs. 2 with SQL. Try not to join yourself. Use navigation properties.

Comment: thanks @GertArnold. As you mentioned changed the join that works well to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Some sample output data would probably help to troubleshoot.

My first suspect would be some sort of capitalization or something. SQL isn't case sensitive normally (unless someone sets it) and that has thrown a few similar results for me in the past.